# XAML: x:Array of static resources

Tags: wpf, staticresource

I have a number of `BitmapImage`s declared in my `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="LockImageSource"   UriSource="img/lock.png"   />
<BitmapImage x:Key="UnlockImageSource" UriSource="img/unlock.png" />
...
```

My converter takes an array parameter of two `ImageSource` elements to choose one of images to show depending on passed value:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=IsLocked,
                   Converter={StaticResource AlteringConverter},
          ConverterParameter={StaticResource LockUnlockImageSourcePair}}"
       Width="16" Height="16" />
```

**How should `LockUnlockImageSourcePair` resource look like?**

```
<x:Array x:Key="LockUnlockImageSourcePair" Type="{x:Type BitmapImage}">
    <??? />
    <??? />
</x:Array>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a Binding with a Converter and complicated ConverterParameter, you could use this simple Style with a DataTrigger:

```
<Image Width="16" Height="16">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource UnlockImageSource}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource LockImageSource}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

If you want to reuse the Style for multiple Image controls, you may declare it as resource:

```
<Style x:Key="LockUnlockImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource UnlockImageSource}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource LockImageSource}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
...

<Image Style="{StaticResource LockUnlockImageStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your way is much easier!